# How to generate an image number of times in android

Tags: android

I have an image that rotates on screen. Now the problem is, I want to generate this image again and again on screen, after 10 seconds. I tried a lot using for loop. But its not working. I want to generate the same rotating image again and again on screen. Please help. Thanks in advance. Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int draw_x = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()
            % (this.getWidth() * 2));
    int draw_y = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis()
            % (this.getHeight() * 2));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        if (draw_x > this.getWidth())
            draw_x = (this.getWidth() * (2)) - draw_x;
        if (draw_y > this.getHeight())
            draw_y = (this.getHeight() * (2)) - draw_y;
        if (draw_x > this.getWidth())
            draw_x = (this.getWidth() * (2)) - draw_x;
        if (draw_y > this.getHeight())
            draw_y = (this.getHeight() * (2)) - draw_y;

        canvas.drawBitmap(eBall, draw_x, draw_y, null);
        image.add(eBall);


         float time = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
                     while ((time+50000)>System.currentTimeMillis());
         i++;
        Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Busy loop is **definitely** BAD IDEA. Never do that. You should use android animation framework for this and rotate your view or use `Handler()` and post delayed `Runnable`:

```
Handler h = new Handler();

....

protected Runnable mTick = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       methodThatRotatesTheImage();

       h.postDelayed( this, delayInMillis );
   }
}
```

and to start this you just do:

```
h.post( mTick );
```

and to stop:

```
h.removeCallbacks( mTick );
```

Comment: I tried this. But its not working. Can you please share the detail code. Please. The code that I shared creates an image and rotate it automatically on screen. Or can you please share links of animation tutorials that will be helpful for task I want to perform. As I am new to android, I have not work with animation. So please. Thanks.

Comment: Rotate means I want to move that image automatically on screen and generate N number of same images.